# pip and setuptools installation without internet

Tags: python

I am in a situation I don't have internet accessibility, I have pip and setup tools source file. I have python 3 zip file downloaded from official website. How can I install them . Besides it is amazing I can't find answers using google, all tells me using ez_install.py and get-pip.py to install which require internet.

Comment: Assuming you have the zip file of the package, `pip install somepackage.zip`… I believe pip itself can be installed easily. In fact it comes by default with python 3.4+

Comment: @Evert I can't use msvc compiler, I also didn't find them unpacking the zip file, amazing! I feel like I live in another world

Comment: @Evert> they come included with python 3.4 and newer. And if that fails, `pip` documentation, section `Installation` covers this: `python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=/local/copies`

Comment: @spectras I cannot use exe installer, only a zip file

Comment: @Evert I can unpack the file, there are only python.exe and  pythonw.exe , no bin directory no pip

Comment: Ha, windows… yeah, the [official release](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), assuming that's what you are using, packs most libraries into a large DLL file. To access modules you must launch python and load them manually wiht `-m modulename`.

Comment: @Evert you can go to official website download file named python-3.6.2-embed-amd64.zip, unpack it

Comment: @Svandex> it has many files, including the main python dll, `python36.dll`, 3.4MB and the zip file next to it. That's where most modules live.

Comment: @spectras yes. python3.dll，but using python -m pip still can't load pip module

Comment: @spectras yes, you unpack the zip file, no pip and setuptools

Comment: Wait, I just realized… that's the embeddable version right? It's very likely they left many things out on purpose, since it's not intended to be a "live" version with many applications using it. If they left out pip, you'll probably have to either get it manually (with get-pip.py), or pick a full python distribution instead of that one.

Comment: @spectras but I don't have access to internet. I can't use get-pup.py

Comment: @Evert I don't have access to installation right. I am not an administrator

Comment: @Svandex> we're back to comment #6. PIP documentation, section installation, explains how to install from a local copy. Basically drop all zip files in a directory and pass it to `--find-links` option of `get-pip.py`.

Comment: @spectras I use the --find-links option, there exist an error. Line 82 in bootstrap, typeerror, expect str, bytes, or is.pathlike object